# Search is empty string or no match from API call

Tags: javascript, api

How do i catch and print a message to the user if the search is an empty string or couldn't find any match from the api on the value in the input field.

```
// show the search results from user input
const searchTvShows = ({ target }) => {
    fetch(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${target.value}`)
        .then(blob => blob.json())
        .then(shows => {
        const app = document.getElementById('app');
        app.innerHTML = shows.map(({ show }) => `
            <div class="col-sm movie-content">
                <div class="movie-image">
                    ${show.image ? `<img src="${show.image.medium}">` : `<img class="fallbackImage"src="design/icons/No_image_available.svg">`}
                </div>
                <div class="movie-info">
                    <h1>${show.name}</h1>
                </div>
          </div>

        `).join(' ');
    })
  }
```

Comment: What does the api return when there are no results?

Comment: Side note: Like a **lot** of people, you're missing out two very important things in the above: 1. You need to check the `ok` property on the response, `fetch` doesn't reject unless the network failed (404s, for instance, still resolve). 2. You need to handle errors (e.g., `.catch(err => { /* handle it */ })`.

Comment: The fetch gets the div with class app so we could just append another div inside "app". But i dont know if we can use the same fetch ....
When there is no result it returns just blank where the results should be

Comment: @Lacon, please undelete your Code Review thread `Simplify Javascript Code`. I have been reviewing it for the last **one and a half hour**. It would be great if you could put it back online so I can give you my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked, and your API returns an empty array when there's a successful search for no match, so:

```
if (shows.length) {
    // do what you're doing
} else {
    // show a message saying there were no matches
}
```

In context, and also dealing with the issues I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879152/search-is-empty-string-or-no-match-from-api-call/50879227#comment88760388_50879152):

```
const searchTvShows = ({ target }) => {
  fetch(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${target.value}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return response;
      })
      .then(blob => blob.json())
      .then(shows => {
        const app = document.getElementById('app');
        if (shows.length) {
          app.innerHTML = shows.map(({ show }) => `
              <div class="col-sm movie-content">
                  <div class="movie-image">
                      ${show.image ? `<img src="${show.image.medium}">` : `<img class="fallbackImage"src="design/icons/No_image_available.svg">`}
                  </div>
                  <div class="movie-info">
                      <h1>${show.name}</h1>
                  </div>
            </div>
          `).join(' ');
        } else {
          app.innerHTML = "<em>No matching shows</em>";
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Report the error or similar
      })
}
```

You can avoid the `if`/`else` if that's important to you (it seems to be to some) by using `||`:

```
const searchTvShows = ({ target }) => {
  fetch(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${target.value}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return response;
      })
      .then(blob => blob.json())
      .then(shows => {
        const app = document.getElementById('app');
        app.innerHTML = shows.map(({ show }) => `
            <div class="col-sm movie-content">
                <div class="movie-image">
                    ${show.image ? `<img src="${show.image.medium}">` : `<img class="fallbackImage"src="design/icons/No_image_available.svg">`}
                </div>
                <div class="movie-info">
                    <h1>${show.name}</h1>
                </div>
          </div>
        `).join(' ') || "<em>No matching shows</em>"; // ***
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Report the error or similar
      })
}
```

That works because with an empty array, `.join(' ')` will return `""`, which is falsy, and so `"" || "<em>...</em>"` results in `"<em>...</em>"`. But if the array isn't empty, you'll have a non-blank string, which will be truthy.